# Error - Building Cardano Node 1.35.4 in Ubuntu Linux 22.04

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, transaction, cabal, ghci

When building cardano-node-1.35.4 using

```
git checkout tags/1.35.4
cabal update
cabal build all
```

I get the following error

```
cabal: Failed to build tx-generator-2.2 (which is required by

test:tx-generator-test from tx-generator-2.2 and exe:tx-generator from

tx-generator-2.2).
```

Upon scrolling up a few lines, I see this

```
src/Cardano/Benchmarking/Script/Setters.hs:40:1: error:

    • Illegal constraint: c NumberOfInputsPerTx

        (Use ConstraintKinds to permit this)

    • In the instance declaration for

        ‘Data.Constraint.Extras.Has c_a3mLE Tag’

   |

40 | deriveArgDict ''Tag

   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can someone please help me understand what this error means and on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think between CHaP movements and upstream updates the build process has started failing for 1.35.4, they've been fixed since on master branch. But for visibility of those using 1.35.4 to build:

1. Failed to build tx-generator-2.2 => This error itself would not prevent you to build `cardano-node` and `cardano-cli` binaries.
2. For those who receive an error with openssl, they'd need to modify cabal.project file as per [this issue](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/4721#issuecomment-1357924401).
3. `cabal install` (running as-is for any component) was broken on that tag, fixed later on master

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this out. Yes, it wouldn’t prevent us from building binaries but the nodes won’t sync up to preview/prepped after that. That is the major issue am facing.

Comment: Sync of node should work fine on preview/preprod once node binary is built, and is actually used for node startup (you can confirm running node version via logs as well if using ScJson)

Comment: Hi @RdLrt, Sadly adjusting the `cabal.project` file did not work. However, I didn't receive any error on the `master` branch.

Comment: You should not use master branch, it may often contain changes that may not be supported by current network[s] or tools

Answer (score 0):

What version of `ghc` are you using? Currently the only supported version is `ghc-8.10.*`.

Work is being done to support `ghc-9.2.*` and when that is supported across the complete stake, then support for `ghc-9.10.*` will be dropped.

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for your response. I am using the 8.10.7.